# ¿Cómo verificar si los datos introducidos son los correctos?

Tags: c

Hice este algoritmo en C que simula un cajero automático de un banco. Funciona todo pero no se como hacer para que me lea las tarjetas que están cargadas en la función llamada `CargaTarjetas`. Es decir, el programa se ejecuta, me pide `dni` y `clave` para ingresar a la cuenta pero yo puedo poner cualquier numero en estas variables que me las toma como correctas.

La idea es que al poner un `dni` y una `clave`, si estas coinciden con alguna de las tarjetas me deje entrar a la cuenta y si no coinciden me diga que los datos son incorrectos. No puedo cambiar las variables por que es para un trabajo y esta determinado que sean las que están. Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

typedef struct{
    int dni;
    int clave;
    float saldo;
    float montoMax;
}TTarjeta;

void CargarTarjetas(TTarjeta *tarj1, TTarjeta *tarj2, TTarjeta *tarj3, TTarjeta *tarj4);
void Ingresar(int *a, int *b);
void VerificarDatosIngreso(int dni, int clave, int *datosOk, TTarjeta *tarjeta);
void SolicitarOperacion(int *op);
void SaldoLimite(TTarjeta *tarjeta);
void Extraccion(TTarjeta *tarjeta);
void CambiarClave(TTarjeta *tarjeta);
void CambiarLimite(TTarjeta *tarjeta);
void RealizarOperacion(int *op);
void Finalizar();

int main(){
    
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Spanish");
    
    int dni, clave;
    TTarjeta t1, t2, t3, t4;
    TTarjeta tarjeta;
    int datosOk;
    int operacion;
    
    CargarTarjetas(&t1, &t2, &t3, &t4);
    Ingresar(&dni, &clave);
    VerificarDatosIngreso(dni, clave, &datosOk, &tarjeta);
    if(datosOk = 1){
        SolicitarOperacion(&operacion);
        RealizarOperacion(&operacion);
        Finalizar();
    }
    else if(datosOk = 0){
        printf("Los datos ingresados son incorrectos.");
        Finalizar();
    }

    return 0;
}

void CargarTarjetas(TTarjeta *tarj1, TTarjeta *tarj2, TTarjeta *tarj3, TTarjeta *tarj4){
    //cargaTarjeta1
    tarj1->dni = 23225226;
    tarj1->clave = 1547;
    tarj1->saldo = 5800;
    tarj1->montoMax = 5000;
    //cargaTarjeta2
    tarj2->dni = 28228331;
    tarj2->clave = 5389;
    tarj2->saldo = 10000;
    tarj2->montoMax = 7000;
    //cargaTarjeta3
    tarj3->dni = 30456189;
    tarj3->clave = 2389;
    tarj3->saldo = 25000;
    tarj3->montoMax = 10000;
    //cargaTarjeta4
    tarj4->dni = 35283281;
    tarj4->clave = 2984;
    tarj4->saldo = 87990;
    tarj4->montoMax = 10000;
}


void Ingresar(int *a, int *b){
    printf("Ingrese su dni : ");
    scanf("%d", a);
    printf("Ingrese su clave : ");
    scanf("%d", b);
}

void VerificarDatosIngreso(int dni, int clave, int *datosOk, TTarjeta *tarjeta){
    if((dni == tarjeta->dni)&&(clave == tarjeta->clave)){
        datosOk = 1;
    }
    else{
        datosOk = 0;
    }
}

void SolicitarOperacion(int *op){
    system("cls");
    printf("Ingrese la operación que desea realizar");
    printf("\n\n1. Consultar saldo y límite de extracción");
    printf("\n2. Extraer dinero");
    printf("\n3. Actualizar clave");
    printf("\n4. Modificar límite de extracción");
    printf("\n\n5. Finalizar");
    printf("\n\nOperación: ");
    scanf("%d", op);
}

void RealizarOperacion(int *op){
    
    TTarjeta *tarjeta;
    
    switch(*op){
        case 1:
            system("cls");
            SaldoLimite(tarjeta);
            break;
        case 2:
            system("cls");
            Extraccion(tarjeta);
            break;
        case 3:
            system("cls");
            CambiarClave(tarjeta);
            break;
        case 4:
            system("cls");
            CambiarLimite(tarjeta);
            break;
        case 5:
            system("cls");
            Finalizar();
            break;
    }
}

void SaldoLimite(TTarjeta *tarjeta){
    
    printf("El saldo en su cuenta es de: %.2lf", tarjeta->saldo);
    printf("\nEl límite de extracción es de: %.2lf", tarjeta->montoMax);
    
}

void Extraccion(TTarjeta *tarjeta){
    
    float montoExtraer;
    float saldoRestante;
    
    printf("Por favor, introduzca el monto que desea extraer\n");
    scanf("%f", &montoExtraer);
    if(montoExtraer > tarjeta->montoMax){
        printf("Se excedió el limite de extracción");
        printf("\nNo es posible realizar la operación.");
    }
    else if(montoExtraer <= tarjeta->saldo){
        
        printf("Retire el dinero de la bandeja");
        saldoRestante = tarjeta->saldo - montoExtraer;
        printf("Su saldo restante en la cuenta es de: %.2lf", saldoRestante);
        printf("\nFin de la transacción");
    }
}

void CambiarClave(TTarjeta *tarjeta){
    
    const int max = 20;
    char claveUno[max];
    char claveDos[max];
    
    printf("Por favor, introduzca su nueva clave: ");
    scanf("%s", &claveUno);
    printf("\nPor favor, vuelva a introducir su nueva clave: ");
    scanf("%s", &claveDos);
    
    if(strcmp(claveUno, claveDos) == 0){
        printf("\nLa clave a sido actualizada con éxito");
        printf("\nSu nueva clave es: %s", claveUno);
    }
    else{
        printf("\nLas claves introducidas no coinciden");
        printf("\nPor favor, intentelo de nuevo...");
    }
}

void CambiarLimite(TTarjeta *tarjeta){
    float montoMaxNuevo;
    
    printf("Por favor, introduzca el nuevo limite de extracción: ");
    scanf("%f", &montoMaxNuevo);
    printf("Su nuevo limite de extracción es: %.2lf", montoMaxNuevo);
}

void Finalizar(){
    printf("\nRetire su tarjeta. Gracias");
    exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: Hasta ahora encontré dos errores. **1.-** El operador de asignación no lo deberías usar para comparar. Así que deberías usar: `if(datosOk == 1)`. **2.-** La estructura al que hace referencia `tarjeta` no tiene asignado ningún dato, entonces, ¿cómo piensas compararlo con los datos que ingrese el usuario? Ahí te toca usar un array de estructuras, donde almacene todas los datos de cada tarjeta y luego cuando el usuario ingrese el DNI y clave, tocará buscar si en el array se encuentra.

Comment: Trate de hacerlo pero me daba muchos errores, seguro lo estoy haciendo mal. Me podes dar un ejemplo de como lo harias el array?

Comment: Pudiste solucionarlo??

Answer (score 2):

**Observaciones**:

**1.-** El operador de asignación (`=`) no lo puedes usar para comparar con otro valor. Lo que debes utilizar en este caso es un [operador relacional o de comparación](https://yosoy.dev/que-son-los-operadores-y-los-tipos-que-existen/) (`==`).

```c
if(datosOk = 1)//Error, esto siempre dará `true`.
```

**Solución:**

```c
if(datosOk == 1)
```

**2.-** La variable `datosOk` es un puntero y en ningún momento modificas el contenido de la variable al que apunte `datosOk`.

```c
if((dni == tarjeta->dni)&&(clave == tarjeta->clave))
        datosOk = 1; //Error
    else
        datosOk = 0;//Error
```

**Solución:** Debes usar el [operador de desreferencia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_de_desreferencia). Con esto lograrás alterar el contenido de la variable `datosOk` (la que fue declarada en el `main`):

```c
if((dni == tarjeta->dni)&&(clave == tarjeta->clave))
        *datosOk = 1;
    else
        *datosOk = 0;
```

**3.-** La estructura al que hace referencia `tarjeta` no tiene ningún dato asignado, por lo tanto, la función `VerificarDatosIngreso` no hará nada.

Aquí necesitas hacer cuatro cosas:

**a)** Declarar en el `main` un *array* de estructuras de `4` elementos.

**b)** Cambiar la declaración de la función `CargarTarjetas`, ahora esta rutina solo acepta únicamente un parámetro.

**c)** El último parámetro de la función `VerificarDatosIngreso` debe recibir la dirección del primer elemento del *array* de estructuras.

**d)** La función `VerificarDatosIngreso` deberá hacer una búsqueda lineal por medio de un bucle `for`. De este modo se podrá verificar si los datos ingresados se encuentra en el *array*. La función también deberá retornar el índice donde se encuentre los datos del usuario en el *array*.

Por lo tanto, en código quedaría así:

```c
void CargarTarjetas(TTarjeta *tarj)
{
    //cargaTarjeta1
    tarj[0].dni = 23225226;
    tarj[0].clave = 1547;
    tarj[0].saldo = 5800;
    tarj[0].montoMax = 5000;
    //cargaTarjeta2
    tarj[1].dni = 28228331;
    tarj[1].clave = 5389;
    tarj[1].saldo = 10000;
    tarj[1].montoMax = 7000;
    //cargaTarjeta3
    tarj[3].dni = 30456189;
    tarj[3].clave = 2389;
    tarj[3].saldo = 25000;
    tarj[3].montoMax = 10000;
    //cargaTarjeta4
    tarj[4].dni = 35283281;
    tarj[4].clave = 2984;
    tarj[4].saldo = 87990;
    tarj[4].montoMax = 10000;
}

int VerificarDatosIngreso(int dni, int clave, TTarjeta *tarjeta)
{
    for(int i = 0; i != N; ++i)
    {
        if((dni == tarjeta[i].dni) && (clave == tarjeta[i].clave))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**5.-** En la función `RealizarOperacion`, se declaró un puntero pero en ningún momento le asignas nada. Con esto el programa ya tiene un [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido#:%7E:text=La%20existencia%20de%20comportamientos%20indefinidos,tipo%20de%20enteros%20sin%20signo.).

Deberías de declarar el puntero `tarjeta` como parámetro y que reciba la dirección de la estructura donde estén los datos del usuario.

**6.-** No necesitas escribir el nombre de cada parámetro cuando declares una función. Eso lo haces cuando definas la función.

**7.-** Cuando una función no recibe argumentos, debes añadir el `void` en los paréntesis.

Sí seguimos cada observación, el código completo quedaría así:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define N  4

typedef struct{
    int dni;
    int clave;
    float saldo;
    float montoMax;
}TTarjeta;

void CargarTarjetas(TTarjeta*);
void Ingresar(int *, int *);
int VerificarDatosIngreso(int, int, TTarjeta*);
void SolicitarOperacion(int *);
void SaldoLimite(TTarjeta*);
void Extraccion(TTarjeta*);
void CambiarClave(TTarjeta*);
void CambiarLimite(TTarjeta*);
void RealizarOperacion(int *, TTarjeta*);
/* El "void" indica que la función NO ACEPTA ARGUMENTOS*/
void Finalizar(void);

int main(void)
{
    
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Spanish");
    
    int dni, clave;
    TTarjeta tarjetas[4];
    TTarjeta tarjeta;
    int index;
    int operacion;
    
    CargarTarjetas(&tarjetas[0]);
    Ingresar(&dni, &clave);
    index = VerificarDatosIngreso(dni, clave, &tarjetas[0]);
    if(index != -1)
    {
        //Asignamos los datos del usuario en la estructura.
        tarjeta.dni = tarjetas[index].dni;
        tarjeta.clave = tarjetas[index].clave;
        tarjeta.saldo = tarjetas[index].saldo;
        tarjeta.montoMax = tarjetas[index].montoMax;
        //Pedimos los datos..
        SolicitarOperacion(&operacion);
        //Realizamos la operación y pasamos la dirección de la estructura donde están los datos del usuario..
        RealizarOperacion(&operacion, &tarjeta);
        Finalizar();
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Los datos ingresados son incorrectos.");
        Finalizar();
    }
    return 0;
}

void CargarTarjetas(TTarjeta *tarj){
    //cargaTarjeta1
    tarj[0].dni = 23225226;
    tarj[0].clave = 1547;
    tarj[0].saldo = 5800;
    tarj[0].montoMax = 5000;
    //cargaTarjeta2
    tarj[1].dni = 28228331;
    tarj[1].clave = 5389;
    tarj[1].saldo = 10000;
    tarj[1].montoMax = 7000;
    //cargaTarjeta3
    tarj[3].dni = 30456189;
    tarj[3].clave = 2389;
    tarj[3].saldo = 25000;
    tarj[3].montoMax = 10000;
    //cargaTarjeta4
    tarj[4].dni = 35283281;
    tarj[4].clave = 2984;
    tarj[4].saldo = 87990;
    tarj[4].montoMax = 10000;
}


void Ingresar(int *a, int *b)
{
    printf("Ingrese su dni : ");
    scanf("%d", a);
    printf("Ingrese su clave : ");
    scanf("%d", b);
}

int VerificarDatosIngreso(int dni, int clave, TTarjeta *tarjeta)
{
    for(int i = 0; i != N; ++i)
    {
        if((dni == tarjeta[i].dni) && (clave == tarjeta[i].clave))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

void SolicitarOperacion(int *op){
    system("cls");
    printf("Ingrese la operación que desea realizar");
    printf("\n\n1. Consultar saldo y límite de extracción");
    printf("\n2. Extraer dinero");
    printf("\n3. Actualizar clave");
    printf("\n4. Modificar límite de extracción");
    printf("\n\n5. Finalizar");
    printf("\n\nOperación: ");
    scanf("%d", op);
}

void RealizarOperacion(int *op, TTarjeta* tarjeta)
{
    
    switch(*op){
        case 1:
            system("cls");
            SaldoLimite(tarjeta);
            break;
        case 2:
            system("cls");
            Extraccion(tarjeta);
            break;
        case 3:
            system("cls");
            CambiarClave(tarjeta);
            break;
        case 4:
            system("cls");
            CambiarLimite(tarjeta);
            break;
        case 5:
            system("cls");
            Finalizar();
            break;
    }
}

void SaldoLimite(TTarjeta *tarjeta){
    
    printf("El saldo en su cuenta es de: %.2lf", tarjeta->saldo);
    printf("\nEl límite de extracción es de: %.2lf", tarjeta->montoMax);
    
}

void Extraccion(TTarjeta *tarjeta){
    
    float montoExtraer;
    float saldoRestante;
    
    printf("Por favor, introduzca el monto que desea extraer\n");
    scanf("%f", &montoExtraer);
    if(montoExtraer > tarjeta->montoMax){
        printf("Se excedió el limite de extracción");
        printf("\nNo es posible realizar la operación.");
    }
    else if(montoExtraer <= tarjeta->saldo){
        
        printf("Retire el dinero de la bandeja");
        saldoRestante = tarjeta->saldo - montoExtraer;
        printf("Su saldo restante en la cuenta es de: %.2lf", saldoRestante);
        printf("\nFin de la transacción");
    }
}

void CambiarClave(TTarjeta *tarjeta){
    
    const int max = 20;
    char claveUno[max];
    char claveDos[max];
    
    printf("Por favor, introduzca su nueva clave: ");
    scanf("%s", &claveUno);
    printf("\nPor favor, vuelva a introducir su nueva clave: ");
    scanf("%s", &claveDos);
    
    if(strcmp(claveUno, claveDos) == 0){
        printf("\nLa clave a sido actualizada con éxito");
        printf("\nSu nueva clave es: %s", claveUno);
    }
    else{
        printf("\nLas claves introducidas no coinciden");
        printf("\nPor favor, intentelo de nuevo...");
    }
}

void CambiarLimite(TTarjeta *tarjeta){
    float montoMaxNuevo;
    
    printf("Por favor, introduzca el nuevo limite de extracción: ");
    scanf("%f", &montoMaxNuevo);
    printf("Su nuevo limite de extracción es: %.2lf", montoMaxNuevo);
}

void Finalizar(){
    printf("\nRetire su tarjeta. Gracias");
    exit(-1);
}
```

**Nota:** En las funciones `CambiarLimite` y `CambiarClave` en ningún momento haces uso del parámetro `tarjeta`.